# Insert Name of Pic Into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have simple code to upload multi pics on my server.. Evrything works fine but I need to inesert picture names in MySql something like 1.png, 2.png, 3.png

Please for help.. I am still learning..

form.html

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p><input type="file" name="img[]"></p>
  <p><input type="file" name="img[]"></p>
  <p><input type="file" name="img[]"></p>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload all files">
</form>
```

upload.php

```
<?php

    if(isset($_FILES['img'])){
        $name_array = $_FILES['img']['name'];
        $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
        $type_array = $_FILES['img']['type'];
        $size_array = $_FILES['img']['size'];
        $error_array = $_FILES['img']['error'];
        for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "pics/".$name_array[$i])){
                echo $name_array[$i]." upload is complete<br>";
            } else {
                echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>";
            }
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: the question is both too broad and unclear. Post what you did try.

Comment: I wanna to insert files names into mysql..... 1.png, 2.png, 3.png

Comment: So, @KikiMiki - what have you *already tried* to insert those image names into your MySQL DB? SO is not a "I need this, give me code" service; there are search engines that you could use for that. A quick use of your favourite search engine will throw up literally thousands of tutorials on how to insert variables into databases...

Answer (score 0):

Try this upload.php:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_FILES['img'])){
      foreach ($_FILES['img'] as $img) {
        $name_array[] = $img['name'];
        $tmp_name_array[] = $img['tmp_name'];
        $type_array[] = $img['type'];
        $size_array[] = $img['size'];
        $error_array[] = $img['error'];
        for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "pics/".$name_array[$i])){
                echo $name_array[$i]." upload is complete<br>";
            } else {
                echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>";
            }
        }
      }
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please save file name in loop like below

```
$file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
```

and then insert after upload

```
$sql="INSERT INTO tbl_uploads(file,type,size) VALUES('$file','$file_type','$file_size')";
 mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: if this for multiple image for multiple records the insert multiple row or if multiple image for one record then insert in one row using sterilize function

Comment: PHP serialize() function

Comment: I uploaded 3 pics , but I have only one record in Mysql which is not correcct at all.. MySql > 1 76984-Array